# Strange starting behavior of firefox, thunderbird, chromium, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, chromium, thunderbird

I am working with Ubuntu 18.04 and notice a strange behavior of 
programs like firefox, thunderbird or chromium:

If I open firefox, it typically takes maybe two minutes until it starts.
Same with thunderbird and chromium.

Now here is the strange thing:
I start firefox - nothing happens
now I start chromium - immediately, firefox opens, chromium does not 
now I start thunderbird - chromium opens.

It works in all combinations. The first program waits until it is triggered 
by the invocation of another program.

Any suggestions?